# vb.net return only selected columns/fields from linq.IQueryable(of out t)

Tags: vb.net, linq

sorry for my English.

I have been searching the web for "Dynamic Linq Queries" and i found one that works on me. [Guide to Creating Dynamic LINQ Queries](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168981/Guide-to-Creating-Dynamic-LINQ-Queries). I converted it to VB on online converter. and the result are

```
  Public Shared Function GetFilteredDataWithPage(Customer As String, Itemdesc As String, JoNumber As String)
    Dim DB As New JoDataClassesDataContext
    Dim DataQuery As IQueryable(Of JoMainTbl) = DB.JoMainTbls

    If Customer.Trim().Length > 0 Then
        DataQuery = DataQuery.Where(Function(a) a.Customer.StartsWith(Customer))
    End If
    If Itemdesc.Trim().Length > 0 Then
        DataQuery = DataQuery.Where(Function(a) a.ItemDescription.StartsWith(Itemdesc))
    End If
    If JobNumber.Trim().Length > 0 Then
        DataQuery = DataQuery.Where(Function(a) a.JoNumber = JoNumber)
    End If
    Return DataQuery
  End Function
```

i have a table with 5 fields

"JONumber, Sample, DateCreated, Customer, ItemDesc"

and to display it

```
DataGridView.DataSource = GetFilteredData(TxtCustomer.Text, TxtItemDesk.Text, TxtJobNumber.Text)
```

The problem is I want it to display the fileds "JONumber, Customer, ItemDesc" only and in this order. all help are much appreciated. thank you in advance.

Comment: Add `Select` call after all the `Where` stuff.

Comment: Im sorry to ask but can you give me the sample code for that. as you can see i just copy and paste this code. I tried to read the tool tip that pop up on visual basic and its really confusing.  i really don't know the linq.IQueryable(of out t).

Comment: Just note that your function doesn't include a return type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MarcinJuraszek suggested in the comment, you should use a `Select` like this:

```
  Public Shared Function GetFilteredDataWithPage(Customer As String, Itemdesc As String, JoNumber As String) 
    Dim DB As New JoDataClassesDataContext
    Dim DataQuery As IQueryable(Of JoMainTbl) = DB.JoMainTbls

    If Customer.Trim().Length > 0 Then
        DataQuery = DataQuery.Where(Function(a) a.Customer.StartsWith(Customer))
    End If
    If Itemdesc.Trim().Length > 0 Then
        DataQuery = DataQuery.Where(Function(a) a.ItemDescription.StartsWith(Itemdesc))
    End If
    If JobNumber.Trim().Length > 0 Then
        DataQuery = DataQuery.Where(Function(a) a.JoNumber = JoNumber)
    End If
    Return DataQuery.Select(Function(x) New With {.JONumber=x.JONumber, .Customer=x.Customer, .ItemDesc=x.ItemDesc})
  End Function
```

Comment: doesn't work. i got error      Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Select' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: See my fix (return of an anonymous object).

Comment: sorry for the late reply. it works now. Thank you so much. i thought i will use the DataGridView.Columns().Visible and  DataGridView.Columns().DisplayIndex to the rest of my program. this save me a lot of coding. thank you again...